# How to access code-behind from AJAX Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I'm relatively new to ASP.NET (Currently studying at university) and I have a good knowledge in C#.

The problem:

I have a MSQL database and a DatabaseConnection class that handles the SQL requests. After I get the data form the database I store it in 3 classes - Person, Project, Task where the Person class holds the user info (role, name, etc.) and 2 lists - List and List.

When the user logs in a Person object is created in the Code Behind with all relevant info from the database. If I refresh/move to another age these objects are being recreated.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
private Person user;

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       user = new Person(User.Identity.Name.ToString());
   }
   //other methods
}
```

1st Question: Is it possible to avoid the recreation of the Person object somehow (keep it without storing it on the client)?

To continue: I now want to get data from these classes and display it using AJAX/JQUERY.

I have created an AJAX Service with a method that gets the project count for the user. The only way I managed to do that is to pass the user name from the HTTPContext to the service - create a new person object and extract the info from there which I want to avoid.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
 [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
  public class AjaxService
 {
[OperationContract]
 public string UserProjectCount(String email)
 {
    Person user = new Person(email);
    String projectCount = user.getProjectsCount() + "";
    return projectCount;       
  }
}
```

and I call this method from the Default.aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var username = '<%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>';
        AjaxService.UserProjectCount(username, OnComplete, OnError);
    }
    function OnComplete(result) {
        var projCount = "" + result;
        $get("myProjects").innerText = " (" + projCount + ")";
    }
    function OnError(errorMessage) {
        alert(errorMessage.get_message());
    }
  </script>
```

2nd Question: Is it possible to access the already created Person object that is currently contained within the CodeBehind page from within the WCF service instead of creating a new one?

3rd: Can I/Should I create a service that holds all these data objects?

I've been trying to figure the above for more than a week now and I'm getting more and more confused. Ant help will be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to avoid the recreation of the Person object somehow
>   (keep it without storing it on the client)?

Yes, with [ASP.NET caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> Is it possible to access the already created Person object
>   that is currently contained within the CodeBehind page from within the
>   WCF service instead of creating a new one?

Yes, cached objects can be used within the service.

> Can I/Should I create a service that holds all these data objects?

You can create a [Service Layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) that returns and manipulates the objects. That can be wrapped by a web service - either WCF or a Restful service.

If the objects you want to store in memory, rather than just disc, are specific to a user's session have a look at [ASP.NET Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.ASPX).

Comment: Yes, a collection of objects (Person, Project, Task) is unique for each user. They are created when the user logs in and I would like to keep them and only update them when required (for example when a user adds a new project) They hold only the data that is related to that particular user. I don't think that storing these objects in a session is a good practice?

edit: Am I still going to be able to save/access these objects using the cache considering the fact that they hold user-specific info?

Comment: "I don't think that storing these objects in a session is a good practice." I avoid using Session but it depends on the requirements. In your case you probably don't need to load all the person's data for each page - therefore, you shouldn't use Session or worry about calling the small amount of data each page needs.

Comment: "Am I still going to be able to save/access these objects using the cache considering the fact that they hold user-specific info?"  If it's all user-specific data then cache isn't much use (depending on the number of users of course).